# Rrsync alternative for this use case on Windows

Tags: windows, remote-access, file-synchronization, diff

On Linux

- Server has a rsync daaemon running, allowing only read requests from clients. It's over HTTP
- Clients sync using `rsync -r ip::public/ . --delete --compress`

Is there similar alternative on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [cwRsync](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync):

- non-free ([older versions](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html) used to be free)
- Windows XP/2003/2008/Vista/7/8/2012
- GUI
- it's basically a port or rsync to Windows (client and server).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://serverfault.com/a/35520/65137) they recommend [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) , GUI around rsync.